# What type of data jsoup connecting is returning

Tags: types, return, jsoup

I was wondering which type of html data jsoup connect is returning.
Actually, when you are visiting a web site, you can see two differents type of data coding

- When you right click and select "View source code"
- When you right click and choose "Inspect element"

I tried to save (by ctrl+s) a webpage and see which type of data coding I get. It was second type. And actually i find elements I wish find.
But, when I am searching a specific class, in the data getting from jsoup connect, i don't find elements i wish find (probably they are added with javascript or something like that). So i supposed i get the first type of data type.

Do you have an idea about the type of data returning ?
Thanks a lot for your answers !

EDIT : Solved. I can't use Jsoup because it doesn't load javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I found some things right here : [https://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/how-to-web-scrape-html-page-after-js-loads/](https://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2014/01/19/how-to-web-srap-html-page-after-js-loads/)

I will try and then feedback.

EDIT : not successful.

Comment: Solved ! 
Jsoup can't load Javacript so I need to use another thing :-)